# Unable to start jupyter notebook in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to make a jupyter notebook in visual studio code but I keep getting this:

> ''Unable to start session for kernel Python 3.8.3 64-bit ('Lenovo':
> virtualenv). Select another kernel to launch with.''

I have anaconda installed and the jupyter notebook works fine in the anaconda navigator. I also tried to use python 3.8.3 base:'conda' but it didnt work. I'm using windows 10

Comment: why dont you try running it directly from the terminal and openning it on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue also occurs on my computer. The solution is to restore the version number of a dependency package "traitlets" of ipython kernel to 4.3.3.

You could try to use "`pip list`" to view the version of the module "traitlets" in the current virtual environment. If it shows version 5.0, it is recommended that you use version 4.3.3.

[image]

You could reinstall "traitlets 4.3.3" with the following command:

> `python -m pip install 'traitlets==4.3.3' --force-reinstall`

If this command is not available, you could use 'pip' to uninstall traitlets5.0 (`pip uninstall traitlets`) and then use 'pip' to install traitlets4.3.3.(`pip install traitlets==4.3.3`)

Reference: [Unable to start session for kernel Python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13701#issuecomment-684994934).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Fix it by uninstalling the Python extension that is linked to that error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using conda to manage your Python environments, activate your target environment at a command prompt, then enter the following:

```
$ conda install traitlets=4.3.3
```

This solved the problem for me.